# Replace a text word for a php included page

Tags: php

I'd like to replace in text `[[banner]]` to an ad banner.

For example:

```
some text...
[[banner]]
some text...
```

I'd like php to find in my text all `[[banner]]` words and include a php page in its place, so the result would be the same as if I did:

```
some text...
<?php include ("banner.php"); ?>
some text...
```

any ideas if it is possible?

Comment: $template = file_get_contents('yourfile.php');
$value = "<?php include (\"banner.php\"); ?>";
$template = str_replace('[[ banner ]]', $value, $template);

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_replace` here should be viable:

```
$input = "some text...\n[[banner]]\nsome text...";
$output = preg_replace("/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/", "<?php include (\"$1.php\"); ?>", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
some text...
<?php include ("banner.php"); ?>
some text...
```

Note that I assume that the name of the PHP script file is whatever text be contained within `[[banner]]`.  If not, then state the logic here.